# Throw an excepion in a unit test to test the catch block with coroutines and stateflow in a ViewModel

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This is my ViewModel and I want to throw an exception so to catch branch is executed.

```
class PopularSearchViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val popularSearchUseCase: LoadPopularSearchUseCase,
    private val coroutineDispatcherProvider: CoroutineDispatcherProvider
) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val listOfCatalogProductMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<CatalogProduct>>(emptyList())
    val listOfCatalogProductStateFlow = listOfCatalogProductMutableStateFlow.asStateFlow()

    fun getPopularProducts() {
        viewModelScope.launch(coroutineDispatcherProvider.io()) {
            try {
                listOfCatalogProductMutableStateFlow.value = popularSearchUseCase.execute()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Timber.e(exception, "popular ${exception.localizedMessage}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the actual unit test. In the mock return I am passing an exception. But when running the test I don't think the exception is thrown so the catch block is never executed.

```
@Test(expected = Exception::class)
fun `should not get popular search products if exception`() {
    runBlockingTest {
        // Arrange
        val listOfEmittedResult = mutableListOf<List<CatalogProduct>>()
        val job = launch {
            popularSearchViewModel.listOfCatalogProductStateFlow.toList(listOfEmittedResult)
        }

        whenever(loadPopularSearchUseCase.execute()).thenThrow(Exception("Something bad happened"))

        // Act
        popularSearchViewModel.getPopularProducts()

        // Assert
        assertThat(listOfEmittedResult).isEmpty()
        verify(loadPopularSearchUseCase).execute()

        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you updated your coroutine test library? Based on that you wrapped the coroutine dispatcher, you will need to make some adjustment for test like make the TestScheduler. Can you include the setup of your test?

Comment: did you try to assert on success?
Actually I'm not sure if you provoke a failure somehow.

Comment: Running into the same thing. I believe it has to do with the way that the unit test framework is designed to suppress/swallow exceptions, minus the ones that the test is looking to be thrown (using assertThrows). Did anyone find a work around?